# aruba access point join uptime and device uptime

Tags: wireless, aruba

just a question how do you determine from the controller the AP device uptime and join uptime to the controller? I'm confused when I run "show ap database". I can see the AP uptime, was that the actual device uptime post reboot or association time?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any specific distinction in the documentation whether that means controller association uptime or hardware uptime since power on.

This debug command might be more useful for you but you may need to contact Aruba to get that level of detail and distinction. They may not consider it relevant. You might be able to test it by rebooting an AP manually and using a timer of your own.

https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/CLI-Bank/Content/aos8/sh-ap-dbg-sys-st.htm